# Creating a thread via implementing runnable interface

Tags: java, multithreading

A Thread can be created via implementing runnable as

```
public class Program  implements Runnable{

public void run(){
   System.out.println("Thread in progress");
}

public static void main(string args[]){
    Program p1 = new Program();
    new Thread(p1).start();

    //we can also use

    (new Thread(new Program())).start();
}

}
```

Is one way preferred over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Program p1 = new Program();
    new Thread(p1).start(); // this thread and the next thread share the same Runnable instance 
   // So, they share the instance level fields also. Thus either one of them can change the state of p1 
    new Thread(p1).start();
    //we can also use

    (new Thread(new Program())).start();
    // This one creates a new instance of Program/ Runnable, thus does not share the same object.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you running only single thread, both ways run exact same. It depends on:
1. Whether you want to reuse back the runnable
2. Whether you need to refer back to attributes inside the runnable.

Use method 2 only if you want to perform something that Fire And Forget.